# Panel Node Page File Selector Variant

Tags: panels

Hello im back using Panels and im hoping it will help with something that ive ran into with the new Media fields etc.

I want to create a Node Page variant that will overide node page if there is a video file linked via the Media Youtube  Multimedia asset    Media file selector file. If there is an image in the Media field then show a differant variant. I think its to do with File types.

Sorry if im a little out my termenology its just D7 hs so many new things to get my head around.

So a panels node page based on variants of what type of file is added to the Media field.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields are usually available as selector rules, so the solution to your problem: find out in which field the content is stored and use a empty/ not empty selection rule for your variant.

variants are selected by order, so the first variant that matches is selected. You could implement two panel variants, one with selection rule for empty, one for not empty, or use only one with selection rule and order the other on underneath that one.